# What is the best approach to use Laravel localization with Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization

I love Laravel localization because it is sample and straightforward, but i dont know how to integrate it whit Vue Components. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in this package to make it easier: https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization

Comment: I wrote about it here https://medium.com/@konafets/localization-with-laravel-and-vuejs-e27068e68ee8. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vue-i18n:

```
$ npm install vue-i18n
```

Add it to you Vue app:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
Vue.use(VueI18n)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just few tips for implementing Laravel resources json-files with Vue **when using Vue 3** (as the implementation of vue-i18n is slightly different compared to Vue 2).

I used to use *martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator*, but it has deprecated and hasn't been maintained for a while, so I upgraded my implementation by switching to https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization.

First I installed Laravel-JS-Localization just as shown at official documentation. This was straightforward. After this I generate JSON-file with:

```
php artisan lang:js --json resources\js\translations.json
```

... Please do note that I do not use default directory (/public) as output directory, because I want to bundle translations to Vue-application.

Next I modified my Vue-applications **app.js** entry point by adding following code before initializing application with createApp(...):

```
const translations = require('./translations.json');

import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'fi',
    messages: {
        fi: translations['fi.strings']
    }
})
```

Remember to **use i18n**, so that you get translation-methods for templates

```
const app = createApp(...)
app.use(i18n);
```

In this example I'm loading Finnish translations, which originally reside at resources/lang/fi.json.

Now I'm able to call **$t('Key to translation')** within my component template, or **this.$t(Key to translation')** within logic.